# Confidence interval in two tailed t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

If I am doing a two tailed $t$ test, i.e my null and alternate hypothesis are

$$H_0: \mu = 0$$
$$H_1: \mu \neq 0,$$

then would I choose and $\alpha$ value of $0.05$ for a $95$% confidence interval or a value of $0.025$?

EDIT: Also, will be degrees of freedom be $n - 2$ or $n - 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a 95% confidence interval and a single test, by definition your significance ($\alpha$) is 5%.

However, this is not the same as the quantile(s) that you will use as a threshold, and I believe that is what is causing your confusion. You wish to chose the boundaries of the confidence interval such that there is only 5% chance of being outside that interval for values sampled according to that distribution. For a symmetric distribution (like the t distribution) and more importantly for a symmetric confidence interval, you pick them so that there is 2.5% chance of being to the left (smaller) of the interval and 2.5% chance of being to the right (larger). Thus, the confidence interval will be between the 2.5 percentile of that distribution and the 97.5 percentile.

Comment: So how do I word this? Am I still going to have my $\alpha$ value as 0.025 or would I need to change it to 0.05? Also, do you know anything about my edit?

Comment: $\alpha$ stays 5%, as per my first sentence. In many formulas regarding confidence intervals, you will find quantiles denoted $t_{\alpha/2}$, matching my explanation above, but that doesn't change $\alpha$ itself. Regarding the edit: whether you use a onesided or twosided test has no influence whatsoever on your degrees of freedom (this makes sense, as this would _change_ the distribution itself).

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know what the degrees of freedom are for this test? It is a t test with unequal variances.

Comment: For the degrees of freedom: find whatever you need at the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_test) page (just scroll down towards unequal variances).

Comment: One final question. Due to this, I got table values using the alpha value of 0.025. That means they're wrong and I need to pick it at 0.05% don't I?

Comment: @Kaish Are you *sure* the table is giving you $\alpha$'s rather than upper tail areas?

Comment: @Glen_b It had both. Like it said 5% and underneath it it said 2.5%. Then I looked on another table which only said 5% and it gave me that value, so I think I looked at the right ones didn't I. If you can double check for me, I has degrees of freedom 30. Does it come to 2.0047 (something like that)?

Comment: Take care whether the $\alpha$'s are for one or two tailed tests. The upper 97.5% point of a $t_{30}$ is 2.042; this would be the appropriate critical value for a 5% two tailed t-test on 30 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good and easy to follow guide on Hypothesis Testing and Confidence intervals. The details and tangible real world explanations and analogies to business concepts where the use of t intervals and hypothesis would be beneficial. It covers independent and dependent testing, equal and unequal variance, large and small sample testing, confidence intervals. It's essentially a killer walk through of the basic concepts of confidence intervals and hypothesis testing.

https://www.kendallhunt.com/uploadedFiles/Kendall_Hunt/Content/Higher_Education/Uploads/CH09_%20Jones_Text.pdf

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the answer?  Link-only answers are generally discouraged.